# Issue in SMTP email sending, ASP .Net mvc application hosted in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to azure. My asp .net MVC application hosted in azure. This application has email sending functionality. When the application is moved to azure, email functionality is not working. My error logs displays error as below:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a65sm9218660oih.6 - gsmtp
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Code block used to send emails

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(GetStringValue(EMAIL_CLIENT), GetIntValue(EMAIL_PORT))
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GetStringValue(EMAIL_USER_NAME),                            GetStringValue(EMAIL_PASSWORD)),
                EnableSsl = sslOn
            };

client.Host = SettingsManager.GetStringValue("EmailClient");//smtp.gmail.com
client.Port = SettingsManager.GetIntValue("EmailPort");//587
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using gmail smtp?

Comment: yes. I'm using gmail smtp.

Comment: Thank you ViVi. I have followed your answer. Now it throws different exception. 

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Comment: Please recheck your credentials and also ensure that a firewall is not blocking access to gmail smtp server.  @bhathiya

Comment: Thank you. In my azure portal there is no option to change settings in firewall. How can I check firewall is blocking access to gmail smtp server in azure?

Answer (score 3):

Even I faced the same issue with gmail. Gmail block your emails from azure, because your app is trying to log in from a location with different timezone or different from the one you used to create the account. Check your gmail inbox and it will have an email regarding blocked login attempt.

> The solution is to either login to gmail from your azure server or
>   check the blocked email in your inbox and add that device to verfied
>   devices. ie select "I recognize this activity as mine" as mentioned in
>   this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en).

Comment: Please recheck your credentials and also ensure that a firewall is not blocking access to gmail smtp server.  @bhathiya

Comment: Thank you. In my azure portal there is no option to change settings in firewall. How can I check firewall is blocking access to gmail smtp server in azure?

Comment: First you need to have access to production server. Find out if there is proxy or firewall. You can also try accessing gmail.com from the azure server to ensure that gmail is accessible.

Comment: My application is hosted as Azure app service and running within a trial period. I can't find firewall or proxy settings.

Comment: This did it for me, I went back to the email where I'm sending the emails from and saw an email regarding blocked sign-in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is fully working code from an app we had at one time hosted on Azure.  The email sent fine through gmail

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("Support@domain.com");
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
mail.Body = "Email body";

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmail-email-address", "gmail-password");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Thanks, Jhorra. My code also similar to your code. But email functionality is not working. My app is hosted as Azure app service. Still, we are within azure free trial period.

Comment: @bhathiya.m Do you have forwarding enabled on your gmail?

Answer (score 1):

First check your code, there is issues on port, credentials, timeout, ...

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{               
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, "yourApplicationSpecificPassword"),
    Timeout = 10000
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{                
    IsBodyHtml = true,               
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body

})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Then in gmail setting, use 2 step verification - 
https://myaccount.google.com/u/3/signinoptions/two-step-verification

and generate app passwd - https://myaccount.google.com/u/3/apppasswords
[image]

use generated passwd in code "yourApplicationSpecificPassword"

good luck!!